# radiant rake issue in extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, radiant

Recently I started using Radiant (edge version from git https://github.com/radiant/radiant.git), But I'm facing little trouble when I try to run rake tasks which are in extensions, As an example

I was successfully able to install paper_clipped extension using

> script/extension install paperclipped

But when I try to run the rake tasks

> rake radiant:extensions:paperclipped:update

it tells me

> Don't know how to build task 'radiant:extensions:paperclipped:update'

But all my other rake tasks are working fine, only the rake tasks inside the extensions giving this error

can any one help me out

I'm on

> ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
>   Rails 2.3.14

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you see the task in the list when you run rake -T?

Answer (score 0):

Radiant pre (currently 1.0.0.RC4) includes its own assets extension based on paperclipped (called "clippy," I think); your best bet is to uninstall paperclipped and stick with the default extension (which you shouldn't need to update if you just installed from edge).

If you really don't want to do that, make sure you are using the correct bundle for your project by running the rake task like so: `bundle exec rake radiant:extensions:paperclipped:update` (you probably want to run `bundle install` or `bundle update` first if you haven't already).

If you don't have bundler for some reason, `gem install bundler`.

Fair warning, this is mostly just guesswork on my part.